# How can I change localdb version in vs2022?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio

I'm developing a project in VS2022 with EF6, using localDB as default instance. My DB is being created code-first and since I have multiple versions of localDB installed, for a matter of compatibility, I wanted the database was created using the 2014 (12.0. 4100.1) version. But it is always created in the 2019 version of LocalDB. Is there any way to specify the LocalDB Version in the project before the DB creation or at any other point?

Comment: Why do you want to use 2014 out of interest? That version is out of mainstream support and has less than a year of extended support left.

Comment: You can change the connection string to point to a different LocalDB instance. Use the `sqllocaldb` utility to find out the instance names that you have installed.